# Diffie Hellman Pre Master Secret too long

Tags: wireshark, diffie-hellman

As far as I understood, when using Diffie Hellman, the pre master secret is generated as follows:

- Alice and Bob agree on a generator `g` and a prime `p`
- Alice chooses a primary key `a`, calculates `A = g^a mod p` and sends the result to Bob
- Bob chooses a primary key `b`, calculates `k = A^b mod p` and receives the pre master secret as a result `k`

However, if I do that with, say, a 4096 bit `p`, `k` also has 4096 bits which seems too large, especially because if I want to hand it over to wireshark in a SSLKEYLOGFILE, wireshark truncates the line after 512 bytes, not reading the whole secret. Is my train of thought correct or is the pre master secret something else?

Comment: 512 Bytes are 4096 bits, so nothing gets truncated. Also, the master secret is (something) mod 4096, so your bitness is fixed to 4096.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser since the values are entered as hexadecimal numbers, 4096 bits become 1024 hexadecimal places, which is more than 512

Comment: Does this link from the wireshark Doku help? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites/42350#42350

Comment: @SmokeDispenser that is exactly what I was trying, I wrote an sslkeylog file containing the line `RSA Session-ID:...sessionid... Master-Key:...the 1024 character hex string...`; wireshark then logged `checking keylog line: RSA Session-ID...` (first 512 bytes) -> `matched session_id`; `checking keylog line:...` (next 512 bytes) -> `unrecognized line`

Comment: @SmokeDispenser: in TLS1.0-2 (and SSL3 cough spit) the master secret is always 48 bytes (384 bits) but the _premaster_ secret varies with different keyexchange methods and parameters. But OP: according to #35639 'RSA Session-ID' should take master not premaster, and only 'PMS_CLIENT_RANDOM' should take premaster.