# How to extract Wireshark keylog from a Java JSSE TLSv1.3 Session

Tags: tls, java, wireshark, jsse

Is it possible to extract the Wireshark keylog information directly from the TLSv1.3 handshake in a Java app? If so, how do I map the fields, or is additional material not shared in the handshake required?

From the following links, I believe I need

NSS Key Log Format for TLSv1.3 connections https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format

Such that I can enable wireshark traffic sniffing https://ask.wireshark.org/question/2691/decrypting-tls-traffic-using-rsa-pre-master-secret/

```
CLIENT_EARLY_TRAFFIC_SECRET is the encryption key for 0-RTT data;
SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET is the key used by the server to encrypt the handshake message;
SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 is the key for encrypting application data on the server side;
CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET is the key used by the client to encrypt the handshake message;
CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 is the key for encrypting application data on the client side.
```

```
No session to resume.
Produced ClientHello handshake message
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "C6 D4 B5 79 08 D9 1D D1 55 94 73 06 09 E0 6B BC C6 BD 71 C2 4F 9C 76 3D C8 46 01 B5 31 6A 93 F9",
  "session id"          : "34 48 28 7C 64 B3 03 37 86 2A 6B EB 7E 51 62 DC 74 80 1E 57 77 01 B7 C5 D5 0D 5C 94 34 B5 70 96",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=www.facebook.com
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)": {
      [h2, http/1.1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [  
        {
          "named group": x25519
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: BC 73 6E 4F 12 5E 8E 42   90 32 56 F6 5C 4F 1A 07  .snO.^.B.2V.\O..
...
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
Consuming ServerHello handshake message
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "EB 32 A7 CA 33 A8 57 E5 DE F2 0D 0F 39 C2 AA 95 0A BF A6 26 48 A0 0B 7E 89 90 0B 4C 39 48 D3 C8",
  "session id"          : "34 48 28 7C 64 B3 03 37 86 2A 6B EB 7E 51 62 DC 74 80 1E 57 77 01 B7 C5 D5 0D 5C 94 34 B5 70 96",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "selected version": [TLSv1.3]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "server_share": {
        "named group": x25519
        "key_exchange": {
          0000: 68 42 BE 6F 3B 35 44 8F   9F 0F D3 86 47 8C AB 97  hB.o;5D.....G...
...
        }
      },
    }
  ]
}
Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.3
Mar 10, 2021 8:45:05 AM sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger log
WARNING: Ignore impact of unsupported extension: supported_versions
Mar 10, 2021 8:45:05 AM sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger log
WARNING: Ignore impact of unsupported extension: key_share
Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
Consuming EncryptedExtensions handshake message
"EncryptedExtensions": [
  "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)": {
    [h2]
  }
]
Mar 10, 2021 8:45:05 AM sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger log
WARNING: Ignore impact of unsupported extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
Consuming server Certificate handshake message
"Certificate": {
  "certificate_request_context": "",
  "certificate_list": [  
  {
    "certificate" : {
      "version"            : "v3",
      "serial number"      : "03 77 ED DC FA F8 BE 34 BA 23 3C 7C 2B 9A 31 7F",
      "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
      "issuer"             : "CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
      "not before"         : "2021-02-10 24:00:00.000 GMT",
      "not  after"         : "2021-05-11 24:59:59.000 BST",
      "subject"            : "CN=*.facebook.com, O="Facebook, Inc.", L=Menlo Park, ST=California, C=US",
      "subject public key" : "EC",
      "extensions"         : [
        {
          ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
          AuthorityInfoAccess [
            [
             accessMethod: ocsp
             accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.digicert.com
          , 
             accessMethod: caIssuers
             accessLocation: URIName: http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt
          ]
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
          AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
          KeyIdentifier [
          0000: 51 68 FF 90 AF 02 07 75   3C CC D9 65 64 62 A2 12  Qh.....u<..edb..
          0010: B8 59 72 3B                                        .Yr;
          ]
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
          BasicConstraints:[
            CA:false
            PathLen: undefined
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
          CRLDistributionPoints [
            [DistributionPoint:
               [URIName: http://crl3.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g6.crl]
          , DistributionPoint:
               [URIName: http://crl4.digicert.com/sha2-ha-server-g6.crl]
          ]]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
          CertificatePolicies [
            [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.2]
          [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
            qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
            qualifier: 0000: 16 1B 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 77 77 77 2E 64 69 67  ..http://www.dig
          0010: 69 63 65 72 74 2E 63 6F   6D 2F 43 50 53           icert.com/CPS
          
          ]]  ]
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
          ExtendedKeyUsages [
            serverAuth
            clientAuth
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
          KeyUsage [
            DigitalSignature
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
          SubjectAlternativeName [
            DNSName: *.facebook.com
            DNSName: *.facebook.net
            DNSName: *.fbcdn.net
            DNSName: *.fbsbx.com
            DNSName: *.m.facebook.com
            DNSName: *.messenger.com
            DNSName: *.xx.fbcdn.net
            DNSName: *.xy.fbcdn.net
            DNSName: *.xz.fbcdn.net
            DNSName: facebook.com
            DNSName: messenger.com
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
          SubjectKeyIdentifier [
          KeyIdentifier [
          0000: A1 DE 5B 01 7E 24 95 35   8A 6B D8 F1 A2 D8 DE 6C  ..[..$.5.k.....l
          0010: F2 7F D0 72                                        ...r
          ]
          ]
        }
      ]}
    "extensions": {
      <no extension>
    }
  },
  {
    "certificate" : {
      "version"            : "v3",
      "serial number"      : "04 E1 E7 A4 DC 5C F2 F3 6D C0 2B 42 B8 5D 15 9F",
      "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
      "issuer"             : "CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
      "not before"         : "2013-10-22 13:00:00.000 BST",
      "not  after"         : "2028-10-22 13:00:00.000 BST",
      "subject"            : "CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
      "subject public key" : "RSA",
      "extensions"         : [
        {
          ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
          AuthorityInfoAccess [
            [
             accessMethod: ocsp
             accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.digicert.com
          ]
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
          AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
          KeyIdentifier [
          0000: B1 3E C3 69 03 F8 BF 47   01 D4 98 26 1A 08 02 EF  .>.i...G...&....
          0010: 63 64 2B C3                                        cd+.
          ]
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
          BasicConstraints:[
            CA:true
            PathLen:0
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
          CRLDistributionPoints [
            [DistributionPoint:
               [URIName: http://crl4.digicert.com/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crl]
          ]]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
          CertificatePolicies [
            [CertificatePolicyId: [2.5.29.32.0]
          [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
            qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
            qualifier: 0000: 16 1C 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 64 69  ..https://www.di
          0010: 67 69 63 65 72 74 2E 63   6F 6D 2F 43 50 53        gicert.com/CPS
          
          ]]  ]
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
          ExtendedKeyUsages [
            serverAuth
            clientAuth
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
          KeyUsage [
            DigitalSignature
            Key_CertSign
            Crl_Sign
          ]
        },
        {
          ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
          SubjectKeyIdentifier [
          KeyIdentifier [
          0000: 51 68 FF 90 AF 02 07 75   3C CC D9 65 64 62 A2 12  Qh.....u<..edb..
          0010: B8 59 72 3B                                        .Yr;
          ]
          ]
        }
      ]}
    "extensions": {
      <no extension>
    }
  },
]
}
Consuming CertificateVerify handshake message
"CertificateVerify": {
  "signature algorithm": ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
  "signature": {
    0000: 30 44 02 20 54 1B D0 4E   1F 4A 1D 81 14 5D 09 13  0D. T..N.J...]..
...
    0040: 80 3D 18 55 09 76                                  .=.U.v
  }
}
Consuming server Finished handshake message
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 82 87 22 9A 5B 35 71 7C   C3 6C F7 09 12 47 76 28  ..".[5q..l...Gv(
...
  }'}
Produced client Finished handshake message
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: AC EF AD 9B 52 3C 8A 2B   B2 EB 9A 4B 11 90 C1 4D  ....R<.+...K...M
...
  }'}
Consuming NewSessionTicket message
"NewSessionTicket": {
  "ticket_lifetime"      : "172,800",
  "ticket_age_add"       : "<omitted>",
  "ticket_nonce"         : "",
  "ticket"               : {
    0000: 6E 93 6F BF 75 B2 6B EE   99 2C C6 F0 7B 13 EE 10  n.o.u.k..,......
...
    0080: D4 13 1C BB 
  }  "extensions"           : [
    <no extension>
  ]
}
```

Session resumed via session tickets

```
Found resumable session. Preparing PSK message.
Produced ClientHello handshake message
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "DD 34 BC EB 28 54 19 09 5F C5 CA F1 83 7E 67 7D FE 3D BB 76 CE 53 59 AB 80 F7 C3 E5 4F 40 4A 53",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=www.facebook.com
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)": {
      [h2, http/1.1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
        "ticket" : {
          0000: 6E 93 6F BF 75 B2 6B EE   99 2C C6 F0 7B 13 EE 10  n.o.u.k..,......
...
          0080: D4 13 1C BB 
        }
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [  
        {
          "named group": x25519
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: DB 61 AF 14 CF BB 63 42   C4 70 2A 71 4C A3 EB 79  .a....cB.p*qL..y
...
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    },
    "pre_shared_key (41)": {
      "PreSharedKey": {
        "identities": {
          {
            0000: 6E 93 6F BF 75 B2 6B EE   99 2C C6 F0 7B 13 EE 10  n.o.u.k..,......
...
            0080: D4 13 1C BB 
          }
        }  "binders": "  {B2 2A 3E 8C 5B 81 22 F2 E7 A4 2A BA F8 41 E9 63 A3 AF 43 84 C7 A0 B9 4C E3 24 BE 76 6D E3 3F 80}",
      }
    }
  ]
}
Consuming ServerHello handshake message
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "8E 9D 63 CE 52 76 5C 6F 36 42 64 BF 6E 4E 7A C6 E5 EA E7 FC 1A 4B 38 7E 6D 3F 42 32 0C 1B 73 8E",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "selected version": [TLSv1.3]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "server_share": {
        "named group": x25519
        "key_exchange": {
          0000: C8 11 0B E3 07 D8 63 DB   1A FF 27 01 8C 9F 72 3F  ......c...'...r?
...
        }
      },
    },
    "pre_shared_key (41)": {
      "PreSharedKey": {
        "selected_identity"      : "0x0000",
      }
    }
  ]
}
Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.3
Resuming session: 
Session(1615365905292|TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
Using PSK to derive early secret
Consuming EncryptedExtensions handshake message
"EncryptedExtensions": [
  "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)": {
    [h2]
  }
]
Consuming server Finished handshake message
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: A4 FE 97 15 DA 48 EE 7D   7A CC D8 B3 82 98 53 89  .....H..z.....S.
...
  }'}
Mar 10, 2021 8:45:05 AM sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger log
WARNING: Ignore impact of unsupported extension: supported_versions
Mar 10, 2021 8:45:05 AM sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger log
WARNING: Ignore impact of unsupported extension: key_share
Mar 10, 2021 8:45:05 AM sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger log
WARNING: Ignore impact of unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
Mar 10, 2021 8:45:05 AM sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger log
WARNING: Ignore impact of unsupported extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
Produced client Finished handshake message
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 4D 4C 7E 7E 1A 85 BB 84   8C 34 B6 8A DC EC 72 03  ML.......4....r.
    0010: 1D 7C C9 61 7E F8 D3 BA   60 72 CB BD 24 30 2B EF  ...a....`r..$0+.
  }'}
Consuming NewSessionTicket message
"NewSessionTicket": {
  "ticket_lifetime"      : "172,800",
  "ticket_age_add"       : "<omitted>",
  "ticket_nonce"         : "",
  "ticket"               : {
    0000: 19 65 E4 36 08 5B 93 1F   BA 42 86 2B 75 5A 6A 0B  .e.6.[...B.+uZj.
...
    0070: BD 46 CC A0 6E A9 45 61   03 39 9A 2E 0C 5D CA 3B  .F..n.Ea.9...].;
    0080: 1A 30 20 AE 
  }  "extensions"           : [
    <no extension>
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wireshark keylog information"? Do you mean the keys used to encrypt traffic?

Comment: NSS Key Log Format for TLSv1.3 connections https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format

To enable wireshark traffic sniffing

Also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites https://ask.wireshark.org/question/2691/decrypting-tls-traffic-using-rsa-pre-master-secret/

Comment: **Not anymore.** The old JSSE log format did include 'KEYGEN' showing premaster, master, and working keys (and ids) which is enough for wireshark. But the new (JSON) format used by all versions that implement TLS1.3 -- including 8u261 up and 11 up -- does not do this; it shows only data sent and received (decoded) and by design that is not enough to reconstruct the secret(s) because if it was then SSL-now-TLS would have been completely and totally broken and not provide any security of any kind at all ever from the first instant. But JSSE _can_ log the data; why do you need wireshark?

Comment: I don't strictly need it. But WireShark will also decide the higher level protocol. HTTP/2 or otherwise. And in a better interactive way than orintln debugging. Maybe I should output a pcap file of the decrypted  data.