# How to decrypt a tls1.3 tcp packets in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, tcp, tcpdump

I generated the public and private key with

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server_key.pem  -out cert.pem`

and I am using c sockets for the server and client with openssl, every thing works fine and I can capture the encrypted traffic using

`sudo  tcpdump -w - -U -i eth0 -v 'port 1337' | tee packets | tcpdump -r -`

serverIP: `10.10.0.6`

clientIP: `10.10.0.12`

My question is: how do you decrypt the traffic in Wireshark with/without using the private key because it does not seem to be working?

I have tried to add the private key: 'Edit'->'Preferences'->'Protocols'->'TLS' then added the `server_key.pem` to the RSA key list with `10.0.0.6` for the ip `1337` for the port and `tcp` as the protocol but I still can't decrypt the packet with the application data.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked up the Wireshark documentation for how to decrypt TLS packets?

Comment: *"then added the server_key.pem"* - this works only for RSA key exchange, which is long obsolete and is not an option anymore with TLS 1.3.  See https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#tls-decryption for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decrypting TLS in Wireshark when using DHE\_RSA ciphersuites](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich every thing seems to mention http and the using a browser to create some sort of a log file but i don't get how I can use this method to decrypt traffic from tcp sockets

Comment: @anon: TCP sockets don't do SSL but a TLS library on top of this does it. This library needs to create the specific file. If it does not - no luck.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich do you mind explain how to do so

Comment: *"how to do so"* - this depends on the specific program or code, i.e. too much unknown about your specific scenario.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i am using c language and programing on a linux machine, could you please tell me what i should search for I just need guidance

Comment: This is more a code question on how to create the necessary file. But if you are using OpenSSL see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_get_keylog_callback.html